# can i add textBox in GridView and get the valuew

Tags: asp.net

I want add textBoxes in a gridVew.  I can do that, but this textBox which comes with each row in the gridView.  I CANNOT handle it; i can not even use its ID.  I want tl reach these textBoxes that comes with each row and get the values that was inserted into them.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the row and cell that the textbox you want is in, you can retrieve it as general control and cast it as a TextBox.

```
//assuming its the only control in the cell (or the first) it will be at index 0
TextBox tb = myGridView.Rows[i].Cells[c].Controls[0] as TextBox;
```

Or knowing the ID you could do this too:

```
TextBox tb = myGridView.Rows[i].Cells[c].FindControl("txtID") as TextBox;

string txtStr = tb.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the other hand, you can just use jQuery to read/manipulate your text boxes, since you would know their id's.

Another approach would be to build your grid on the fly, but it would be a lot of extra work.